# How to find last line in a mapreduce job

Tags: java, hadoop

I am processing a `.csv`file. I would like to print only my first and last lines. I have accomplished this using normal Java code but, I did not find any `Inputformat`which will read the lines and find first and last line. My Java code is as as below.

```
public class CSVToJSON {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException { 
    File file = new File("/../Desktop/ABCD.txt");
    try  {
    BufferedReader csvFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/../Desktop/.csv")); 
    BufferedWriter jsonFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonNew.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    jsonFile.write(jsonNew);
    jsonFile.newLine();
    String next, fileContent = csvFile.readLine();
    for (boolean first = true, last = (fileContent == null); !last; first = false, fileContent = next) 
    {
       last = ((next = csvFile.readLine()) == null);
       if (first) 
    {
       String[] tab = fileContent.split(",");
       String line = "[" + tab[2] + "," + tab[3] + "," + tab[8] + "," + tab[11] + "," + tab[15] + "," + tab[16] + "],";
       InputStream inputStreamNew = new ByteArrayInputStream(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
       jsonFile.write(line);
       jsonFile.newLine();
    }else if (last) {
        String[] tab = fileContent.split(",");
        String lineLast = "[" + tab[2] + "," + tab[3] + "," + tab[8] + "," + tab[11] + "," + tab[15] + "," + tab[16] + "]" + "\n" + "];
        InputStream inputStreamNewLine = new ByteArrayInputStream(lineLast.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        jsonFile.write(lineLast);
        jsonFile.newLine();
    }else {
        String[] tab = fileContent.split(",");
        String line = "[" + tab[2] + "," + tab[3] + "," + tab[8] + "," + tab[11] + "," + tab[15] + "," + tab[16] + "],";
        inputStream inputStreamNormalLine = new ByteArrayInputStream(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        jsonFile.write(line);
        jsonFile.newLine();
    }
    }
        csvFile.close();
        jsonFile.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         Logger.getLogger(CSVToJSON.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(CSVToJSON.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
```

Comment: What is occurring or what error is received, and on what line of code does that happen to you?

Comment: I am not able to print the last lie. That means, I am unable to decide which InputFormat to use. I used the above logic in my Map reduce code. But, this dosent suit because hadoop dosenot provide a mechanism to find last line. However, I implemented a counter to find first line.

Comment: I'm outdated on my Java, as it looks like the for loop has extra arguments(thought it typically accepts 3 expressions), and it didn't complain.  I have a feeling the issue lies in the incrementation, are you getting everything but the last line?

Comment: In this code I am getting the last line also. However, I am unable to use this logic in Mapreduce code. How will textinputformat process lines based on conditions. I guess its not the right choice.